# Plotnine, changing order of Months on x axis, currently alphabetically

Tags: python, plotnine

Using Plotnine to plot values per month.
Currently, the Months are ordered alphabetically on x axis.
How to change this?

here is the code:

```
(ggplot(df, aes(x = 'Month', y='Rented Bike Count')) + 
stat_summary(fun_data = 'mean_sdl', geom = 'bar') +
theme(axis_text_x = element_text(angle=90)))
```

and the plot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

just found out the solution:

```
months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", 
          "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
(ggplot(df, aes(x = 'Month', y='Rented Bike Count')) + 
stat_summary(fun_data = 'mean_sdl', geom = 'bar') +
scale_x_discrete(limits=months) +
theme(axis_text_x = element_text(angle=90)))
```

Comment: A better option is to make `df['Month']` a categorical were the categories have the order you want.